# Installation of RStudio x64 fails on Ubuntu (GNOME) 16.10 - dependency problems

Tags: ubuntu, installation, rstudio

After a fresh install of *Ubuntu GNOME 16.10*, I cannot install *RStudio Desktop x64* anymore.

I was trying to install the latest `*.deb` file via

```
sudo dpkg -i ./rstudio-0.99.903-amd64.deb
```

which resulted in

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of rstudio
rstudio depends on libjpeg62; but:
Package libjpeg62 is not installed.
rstudio depends on libgstreamer0.10-0; but:
Package libgstreamer0.10-0 iis not installed.
rstudio depends on ibgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0; but:
Package libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0 is not installed.
```

I have tried to install libgstreamer via:

```
sudo apt-get install libgstreamer0.10-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev
```

which also resulted in an error:

```
E: Package libgstreamer0.10-dev coulnd not be found. [...]
```

It seems that [on debian the problem could be solved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37550993/rstudio-installation-failure-under-debian-sid-libgstreamer-dependency-problems), but for Ubuntu 16.10 I am not sure what to add to the sources.list to follow the same instruction.
Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: "RStudio have a new preview out that doesn't require libgstreamer0.1 (it uses the new libgstreamer1.0 in Ubuntu 16). You can try it here:

https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/preview/                                                                                 This will become the stable build in the next few weeks." Says Jonathan of RStudio in a post you can see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40413323/rstudio-install-on-ubuntu-16-10-fails-due-to-libgstreamer/44851086#44851086

Answer (score 11, accepted):

EDIT: RStudio developer Jonathan points out that this is no longer necessary, as a new version of RStudio is out that doesn't have the troublesome dependency. You can get that version here:
https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/preview/

For a similar solution, but one that includes additional instructions for making sure that the outdated packages don't get updated away, see the alternative below. Thanks to [Mike Williamson](https://mikewilliamson.wordpress.com/2016/11/14/installing-r-studio-on-ubuntu-16-10/) for excellent instructions, reproduced below:

1) Get the latest R Studio Daily Build [here](https://www.rstudio.org/download/daily/desktop/ubuntu64/), though note that it's not necessarily stable.

2) Install, chaning the name of the package to the one you downloaded - perhaps easiest if you go to your Downloads directory - and you'll probably find that there are missing packages:

`sudo dpkg -i rstudio-1.0.124-amd64.deb`

3) Download the missing packages (the lack of which causes the installation to fail):

`wget http://ftp.ca.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gstreamer0.10/libgstreamer0.10-0_0.10.36-1.5_amd64.deb`

`wget http://ftp.ca.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gst-plugins-base0.10/libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0_0.10.36-2_amd64.deb`

4) Install them:

`sudo dpkg -i libgstreamer0.10-0_0.10.36-1.5_amd64.deb`

`sudo dpkg -i libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0_0.10.36-2_amd64.deb`

5) Make sure they don't get over-written at the next software update:

`sudo apt-mark hold libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0`

`sudo apt-mark hold libgstreamer0.10`

6) Install RStudio (changing name to the version you downloaded):

`sudo gdebi rstudio-1.1.5-amd64.deb`

7) Launch RStudio:

`rstudio`

Comment: You can now get a version of RStudio that doesn't have this dependency issue: https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/preview/

Answer (score 17):

This is what i done in Ubuntu 16.10

1. Download "libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0_0.10.36-2_amd64.deb"

   from https://packages.debian.org/jessie/amd64/libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0/download
2. Download "libgstreamer0.10-0_0.10.36-1.5_amd64.deb"

   from https://packages.debian.org/jessie/amd64/libgstreamer0.10-0/download
3. Install two packages above
4. sudo apt install libjpeg62 libedit2
5. finally install rstudio-0.99.903-amd64.deb

I also used "sudo gdebi ..." to install packages instead "sudo dpkg -i  ..."

Comment: Works for Ubuntu 17.10 as well

Comment: Works for Debian Stretch as well to install `rstudio-1.1.463-amd64.deb`. The `libjpec62` and `libedit2` were not needed (mentioned in point 4 of the above answer). Only the `libgstreamer0.10-0_0.10.36-1.5_amd64.deb` and `libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0_0.10.36-2_amd64.deb` packages were needed for the rstudio install to work.

Answer (score 0):

It is done with

```
Download "libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0_0.10.36-2_amd64.deb"
from https://packages.debian.org/jessie/amd64/libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0/download

Download "libgstreamer0.10-0_0.10.36-1.5_amd64.deb"
from https://packages.debian.org/jessie/amd64/libgstreamer0.10-0/download

Install two packages above

sudo apt install libjpeg62 libedit2

finally install rstudio-0.99.903-amd64.deb
```