# Problems installing R packages on Linux Mint 18.1

Tags: r, rstudio, linux-mint

So I've been attempting to install the Shiny and Devtools R packages, but I'm running into the same kind of error as below: no matter what kind of package it always has a non-zero exit and includes the "error: unknown type name ‘FILE’" message. An example is below. For the record, I've already run the apt-get update and upgrade commands, tried reinstalling R and RStudio, etc. but I keep running into this issue.

Here's my /etc/apt/sources.list:

```
#deb cdrom:[Linux Mint 18.1 _Serena_ - Release amd64 20161213]/ xenial contrib main non-free
deb http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/
deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/
```

I'm stuck on this one, can anyone help me figure out what to do to get these R packages to install correctly? I have not had any luck trying it via RStudio's IDE or via the CLI...what's missing here?????

```
install.packages("tibble")
Installing package into ‘/home/lennys/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependency ‘lazyeval’

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/lazyeval_0.2.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 317272 bytes (309 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 309 KB

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/tibble_1.2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 54517 bytes (53 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 53 KB

* installing *source* package ‘lazyeval’ ...
** package ‘lazyeval’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c expr.c -o expr.o
In file included from expr.c:3:0:
/usr/share/R/include/Rinternals.h:1042:48: error: unknown type name ‘FILE’
 void R_InitFileInPStream(R_inpstream_t stream, FILE *fp,
                                                ^
/usr/share/R/include/Rinternals.h:1045:50: error: unknown type name ‘FILE’
 void R_InitFileOutPStream(R_outpstream_t stream, FILE *fp,
                                                  ^
/usr/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:132: recipe for target 'expr.o' failed
make: *** [expr.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘lazyeval’
* removing ‘/home/lennys/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/lazyeval’
ERROR: dependency ‘lazyeval’ is not available for package ‘tibble’
* removing ‘/home/lennys/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/tibble’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpvLx4dw/downloaded_packages’
Warning messages:
1: In install.packages("tibble") :
  installation of package ‘lazyeval’ had non-zero exit status
2: In install.packages("tibble") :
  installation of package ‘tibble’ had non-zero exit status
>
```

A little more information: I've been trying to work this out, still no success. I keep seeing this repeatedly though:

```
In file included from print_stderr.c:2:0:
/usr/share/R/include/Rinternals.h:1042:48: error: unknown type name ‘FILE’
 void R_InitFileInPStream(R_inpstream_t stream, FILE *fp,
                                                ^
/usr/share/R/include/Rinternals.h:1045:50: error: unknown type name ‘FILE’
 void R_InitFileOutPStream(R_outpstream_t stream, FILE *fp,
```

Answer (score 1):

I have no answer, but I can only tell you that

- CRAN tests on Debian and Fedora, and it of course it works there
- Lost of folks use Ubuntu, Michael builds > 3k packages via his PPA
- Maybe Mint changed the default libraries
- `FILE` is something very plain old C, that *really* should be known
- Your report lacks detail as we cannot tell what compiler, what libc, ... you use

Then again, first things first: do you have package `r-base-dev` installed which ensures a bunch of other dependecies are met?

Lastly, log from my Ubuntu 16.10 laptop:

```
edd@brad:~$ install.r tibble
trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/tibble_1.2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 54517 bytes (53 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 53 KB

* installing *source* package ‘tibble’ ...
** package ‘tibble’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
ccache g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG   -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include"   -fpic  -g -O3 -Wall -pipe -Wno-unused -pedantic -march=native -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
ccache g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG   -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include"   -fpic  -g -O3 -Wall -pipe -Wno-unused -pedantic -march=native -c matrixToDataFrame.cpp -o matrixToDataFrame.o
g++ -Wl,-S -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o tibble.so RcppExports.o matrixToDataFrame.o -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
installing to /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/tibble/libs
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (tibble)

The downloaded source packages are in
        ‘/tmp/downloaded_packages’
edd@brad:~$
```

Standard advise: maybe ask on r-sig-debian as other Mint users lurk there.

Comment: Thanks for your input Dirk. Sadly, I never found a workable solution for this, so instead I just wiped my hard drive and switched to Ubuntu 16.04. It still seems strange that it wouldn't work in Mint but does in Ubuntu, but that might be due to some oversight on my part.

Answer (score 0):

I've been doing this long enough to know that if I wanted to install RStudio & R, then had better check and find out how to beforehand. So I wasn't suprised when the query (ubuntu mint 16.10 rstudio install apt-get) didn't return anything that resembled an usable answer. So, I did the investigation, and managed to stumble across the following URLs, which articulate the problem, and describe a command line solution to get things functional, and working.

If this has been fixed, that would be cool, but my sense is that because inherent Yak Shaving (http://sethgodin.typepad.com/seths_blog/2005/03/dont_shave_that.html) SNAFU levels being what they are with the Ubuntu v16.04 to v16.10 non-functionalities, that these fix descriptions are still viable, and probably act as a pretty good template for the fix of simillarly broken other packages.

- Installing R-Studio on Ubuntu 16.10 (https://mikewilliamson.wordpress.com/2016/11/14/installing-r-studio-on-ubuntu-16-10/)
- RStudio install on Ubuntu 16.10 fails due to libgstreamer ([RStudio install on Ubuntu 16.10 fails due to libgstreamer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40413323/rstudio-install-on-ubuntu-16-10-fails-due-to-libgstreamer/40938717#40938717))

Cheers, odoncaoa

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Mint 18.1, and just installed R with:

```
sudo apt-get install r-base r-base-dev
```

(I'm guessing just "r-base-dev" was enough.)

As non-root user I then started `r` and typed:

```
install.packages('tibble')
```

It asked mirror, and I chose a geographically close one, and it asked if I wanted to create a local repository (rather than the system-wide one), and I said yes.

My output then differs from yours:

```
also installing the dependencies ‘rlang’, ‘Rcpp’

trying URL 'https://cran.ma.imperial.ac.uk/src/contrib/rlang_0.1.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 201419 bytes (196 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 196 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.ma.imperial.ac.uk/src/contrib/Rcpp_0.12.11.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2485092 bytes (2.4 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 2.4 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.ma.imperial.ac.uk/src/contrib/tibble_1.3.3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 91511 bytes (89 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 89 KB
```

I.e. tibble is version 1.3.3, not 1.2, and rcpp and rlang are dependencies, not lazyeval. But I doubt that is related to the error message you are getting, and more to do with something that changed between February and June.

I see from another answer that you gave up and re-installed the OS (the Mint/Ubuntu differences would not be causing the errors you see). I suspect a less extreme solution would've been to uninstall r, and reinstall, making sure it was 'r-base-dev' you were installing. And if it continued, to uninstall and reinstall 'gcc', as complains about `FILE` are a sign the C compiler installation is seriously screwed up.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I'd resolved it:

- uninstall the R: sudo apt-get remove r-base-core
- uninstall the rStudio: sudo apt-get remove rstudio

And after it, reinstall R:

- sudo apt-get install r-base r-base-dev
- reinstall o rStudio and finally I got it make dowload of packages